# How to detect whether a "text/writeable" field is focused

Tags: autohotkey

How do I detect whether a text/writable field is focussed?

By text/writable field, I mean e.g. notepad; this SO-text field; the address-bar of Chrome, etc. Basically anything that you are supposed to write into.

Comment: Requires AHK_L, but it may be of use: [Link](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/61325-detecting-if-text-field-or-text-cursor-is-active-while-in-a/?p=386651)

Comment: @Spyre AHK_L is the official AHK nowadays. L comes from Lexikos who forked the original AHK in 2009 and continued its development. AHK_L was then made the official AHK version and renamed from AHK_L to AHK.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you for the info @0x464e!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [ControlGetFocus](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetFocus.htm), it lets you get which control of a target window that has input focus. What kind of window will really make a difference, IE is pretty doable, Notepad++ also doable, Chrome would require special code for example: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/103178-how-to-get-the-current-url-in-google-chrome/#entry637687.

Example of getting the control of the active window that works pretty well:

```
!z::
activeWindow := WinExist("A")
ControlGetFocus, focusedControl, ahk_id %activeWindow%

if(ErrorLevel) {
    MsgBox, Couldn't get focusedControl
} else {
    ControlGetText, focusText, %focusedControl%
    
    if(ErrorLevel) {
        ControlGetText, focusText,, ahk_id %activeWindow%
        Msgbox, Focused window text: %focusText%
    } else {
        Msgbox, Focused control text: %focusText%
    }
    
}
return
```

So you would want to find out the identifier of what ever field you were interested in and check if it has focus when you want to know, or maybe regularly with [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).